# Prove that $f_n$ converges to 0 in $L^1$ norm and $L^2$ norm

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Hello I have problems with this exercise

Let $f_n (t) = t^n$ seen as a sequence in $C [0, 1]$: Prove that $f_n$ converges to $0$ in $L^1$ norm and $L^2$ norm; but not in norm of the supreme.

I need a hint, please.

Thansk

Comment: First calculate to which function converges $\{f_n\}$ when $n\to\infty$, let's call it $f$ (i.e, calculate $f$ such tht $f_n \to f$) and then calculate $||f||_1, ||f||_2, ||f||_\infty$. Once you've done that, use the definition of convergence of functions in the proof. Remember you have to study the function only for values between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $0$ denote the zero function. We have
$$\|f_n - 0\|_1 = \int_{[0, 1]}|f_n| = \frac{1}{n + 1}.$$
Since $\frac{1}{n + 1} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, this proves convergence in $L^1$.

Similarly, we see that
$$\|f_n - 0\|_2 = \left(\int_{[0, 1]}|f_n|^2\right)^{\frac12} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n + 1}} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0.$$

On the other hand, for the $\sup$ norm, we have $\|f_n - 0\|_\sup = 1$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. Indeed, note that for $x \in [0, 1]$, we have $$|f_n(x) - 0(x)| = |x^n| \le 1$$
and so $\|f_n - 0\|_\sup \le 1$. On the other hand, the bound is actually obtained at $x = 1$. Thus, the $\sup$ norm of $f_n - 0$ is $1$.

In particular, $\|f_n - 0\|_\sup \not\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.